# Spaces while using "Print" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, file-io, csv

For some reason I am getting a lot of spaces in front of each value while trying to print to a flat text file.

```
'append headers
Cells(start_row - 2, 1).Select
For i = 1 To ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Column = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column Then
        Print #finalCSV, Cells(start_row - 2, i) & "\n",
    Else
        Print #finalCSV, Cells(start_row - 2, i) & ",",
    End If
Next i
```

Example output:

```
DC Capacity:hi,             Resistive Capacity:lo,      Resistive Capacity:hi,      Reactive Capacity:lo,
```

Is there any way to get rid of these spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Print #finalCSV, Cells(start_row - 2, i) & ",";
```

If I remember my VB correctly, a comma inserts a tab, while a semicolon just suppresses the newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
Print #finalCSV, Trim(Cells(start_row - 2, i)) & ",",
```

Answer (score 0):

Vincent's answer is right but I want to make it even more clear:

> Print #finalCSV, Cells(start_row - 2, i) & ",",

will give this kind of output:

```
> DC Capacity:hi,             Resistive Capacity:lo,      Resistive
> Capacity:hi,      Reactive Capacity:lo,
```

and using semicolon at the end of the sentence:

> Print #finalCSV, Cells(start_row - 2, i) & ",";

will give you this output:

```
> DC Capacity:hi,Resistive Capacity:lo,Resistive Capacity:hi,Reactive
> Capacity:lo,
```